# irony-mode does not pick up include paths

Tags: emacs, cc-mode

I've recently started using [`irony-mode`](https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode) for completion in emacs (24.3.1). However, I seem unable to add additional system include paths to package.

I have this code in my config:

```lisp
(defun ac-cc-mode-clang-hooks ()
  (yas/minor-mode-on)
  (auto-complete-mode 1)

  ;; avoid enabling irony-mode in modes that inherits c-mode, e.g: php-mode
  (when (member major-mode irony-known-modes)
       (irony-mode 1))

  ;; set compiler flags to include header files
  (setq irony-compile-flags '("-Iinc"))
  (irony-reload-flags))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'ac-cc-mode-clang-hooks)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'ac-cc-mode-clang-hooks)
```

irony-mode is loaded correctly and completion works perfectly for include paths which the compiler knows explicitly (i.e. everything printed by `echo "" | g++ -v -x c++ -E -`) but the additional include path `inc` is not picked up (does not matter whether its a relative or absolute path).

However, if I add the information to the `.clang_complete` file and load it using `C-c C-b` the include path is recognised and used. Obviously this is a less than ideal setup because

1. I don't want to create a `.clang_complete` file for each single piece of code I'm working on
2. The `.clang_complete` file is not loaded automatically.

Is there some **working** method (which does not involve a per-project setup, I don't want to create project management files for each piece of code) for telling `irony-mode` where to look for header files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look here: https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode#i-got-an-error-due-to-stdargh-how-to-solve-this

The variable `irony-libclang-additional-flags` should meet your needs.
It should work without calling `irony-reload-flags`.

It's not a buffer-local variable though, so you don't need to put it in the hook.

I would recommend the following:

```
(setq irony-libclang-additional-flags
      (append '("-I" "inc") irony-libclang-additional-flags))
```

Comment: This works perfectly for a global (absolute) path. Two more questions: 1) How do I add multiple paths? Do I use `'("-I" "/IncOne" "-I" "/IncTwo")`, and 2) I think this is not working with relative paths because using your above code does not pick up a header file in the subdirectory `inc`. The logfile says: `1 errors/warnings found during completion.
/tmp/!home!elemakil!Temp!FooBar.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'SomeInc.h' file not found` so I guess that the problem is that copying the source to `/tmp` invalidates relative includes. Can this be fixed?

Comment: 1) Yes.
2) You are right, it's fixed now, thank you for your input.
3) Do not hesitate to make an issue on Github, I stumbled upon this issue by chance.

Comment: Works like a charm now!

Comment: Neither the link you pointed out, nor the variable you mentioned is present at the present moment. I found a variable «irony-additional-clang-options», but for some reason the description admonishes to not use it for a header additional paths. What to use then is unclear.

Comment: I will update my answers but please create an issue on Github for this or post on http://emacs.stackexchange.com/. For now there is no proper way to set the default options, you can use `irony-additional-clang-options` in the meantime but a better alternative will be available in the future.